# git: which files have been changed in both branches

Tags: git

I have 2 branches (A and B with common ancestor X), with multiple commits on each branch. I'd like to know the list of files which have been changed in both branches

`A1 - A2 - A3 - ... - A`

`/`

`X`

`\`

`B1 - B2 - B3 - ... - B`

So to display only files which can be found in both of these lists:

`git diff X..A --name-only`

`git diff X..B --name-only`

Comment: Just pass both through `sort` into temporary files, then `comm` on them.

Comment: no way to do it directly in git ?

Comment: I doubt it. It is way too specific

Comment: @EugeneSh. should post his comment as an answer. Just to mention another way, you can feed the list provided by one command as a path filter to the other one : `git diff --name-only X A -- $(git diff --name-only X B)` (works in bash)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747554/git-which-files-have-been-changed-in-both-branches#comment125070516_70747554) [listed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747554/git-which-files-have-been-changed-in-both-branches#comment125071564_70747554), consider using `git ls-tree -r` on the three commits in question.  The output from `ls-tree` is already sorted, so `comm` works well here.  If a file exists in all three commits with the same hash ID (and mode if you want to capture mode changes), you want to discard it; otherwise you want to include it in your final summary.

No matter which method you chose, you will need to write at least a little bit of code: use `git merge-base` (with `--all` if you want robust checking for a single merge base) to find commit `X`, then generate the file lists with either `git diff` or `git ls-tree -r` and do the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

```
( git diff --name-only A...B; git diff --name-only B...A ) | sort | uniq -d
```

is what you're looking for: files changed since the merge base on each, sorted, with only the duplicates listed.

Comment: for me the expression above doesn't have the requested result, however with this `( git diff --name-only X..B; git diff --name-only X..A ) | sort | uniq -d` it's fine

Comment: Then there's something I missed, because [the definition of diff's three-dot A...B is $(git merge-base A B) B](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203), and I understood your question as saying X is the merge base.

Comment: Ah, I was looking to suggest almost the same, but missed the existence of the `-d` switch in `uniq`